# Is a simulacrum tangible while inside an antimagic zone?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, antimagic-field, simulacrum

The *Simulacrum* spell enables you to make an illusory copy of a humanoid or beast by giving magic to a statue of snow or ice (that contains hair/fingernails/etc.).

While inside an antimagic zone (from the *Antimagic Field* spell, a beholder's eye cone, etc.), spells are suppressed.

If a simulacrum happens to go inside an antimagic zone, does it completely disappear until the zone is displaced, or does it remain there, tangible (in its true ice/snow form)? And if it does remain tangible, is it then destroyable (such as by pushing the ice/snow statue to the ground)?

Such a situation happened in my Tier 4 AL gaming session last Sunday, and I ruled that it was tangible and (easily) destroyable, but perhaps I made an incorrect ruling, hence why I'm double-checking here today.

Answer (score 18):

### The simulacrum would wink out while suppressed

Per the effect description for Antimagic Field:

> A creature or object summoned or created by magic temporarily winks out of existence in the sphere. Such a creature instantly reappears once the space the creature occupied is no longer within the sphere.

The specific effect of the Simulacrum spell is:

> You shape an illusory duplicate of one beast or humanoid that is within range for the entire casting time of the spell. The duplicate ***is a creature***...

Because the created duplicate is a magically created creature, it would wink out of existence within the Antimagic Field.